# Как изменять размер оси OX относительно OY?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Допустим у оси OY максимальное значение 20, но OX может принимать различные максимальные значения (<= 20), как сделать, чтобы ось OX масштабировалась относительно OY. У меня есть subplots на нем несколько графиков, максимальное значение всех графиков 20 по OY, но по OX максимальное значение разное.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать чтобы каждый график масштабировался по OX, то есть у 1 графика ось OX была 1/4(5/20) от оси OY, у графика 2 1/2(10/20)от оси OY и так далее. Но при этом ось OY сохранила свой размер.
Код примера

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 4)
y = np.linspace(1, 20, 20)
x0 = np.linspace(1, 5, 20)
x1 = np.linspace(1, 10, 20)
x2 = np.linspace(1, 15, 20)
x3 = np.linspace(1, 20, 20)

ax[0].plot(x0, y)
ax[1].plot(x1, y)
ax[2].plot(x2, y)
ax[3].plot(x3, y)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну так укажите gridspec при создании subplots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


y = np.linspace(1, 20, 20)
x0 = np.linspace(1, 5, 20)
x1 = np.linspace(1, 10, 20)
x2 = np.linspace(1, 15, 20)
x3 = np.linspace(1, 20, 20)
ratios = [max(x) for x in [x0, x1, x2, x3]]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 4, figsize=(16,9), gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': ratios})

ax[0].plot(x0, y)
ax[1].plot(x1, y)
ax[2].plot(x2, y)
ax[3].plot(x3, y)

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]